# How to dynamically convert non-existing class member functions to existing ones

Tags: python

I have a class:

```
class DataReader:
    def get_data(self, name):
        # get data of given name
```

It's OK that I use it as following:

```
reader = DataReader()
a = reader.get_data('a')
b = reader.get_data('b')
c = reader.get_data('c')
...
```

Is it possible that I write codes like following:

```
a = reader.get_a()
b = reader.get_b()
c = reader.get_c()
```

For current codes, it will fail since class DataReader has no methods like get_a(). What I want is, do something to let DataReader support method like get_a, and automatically convert it to self.get_data('a'), without really define get_xxx methods one by one.

Here, the a, b, c can be any string, and I cannot know all of them while defining DataReader class. So, let me ask my question in another way: is there some shortcut way to let DataReader support all (infinity) get_xxx methods (here xxx can be any string), as if I defined infinity methods like:

```
class DataReader:
    def get_a(self): return self.get('a')
    def get_b(self): return self.get('b')
    ...
    def get_z(self): return self.get('z')
    def get_aa(self): return self.get('aa')
    ...
    def get_asdf(self): return self.get('asdf')
    ...
    def get_okjgoke(self): return self.get('okjgoke')
    ...
```

Comment: How about `reader['a']` that would be easy to implement. You could also overwrite `__getitem__` but you will have to take account of the other attribute of the class and instance.

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you give a reason why not simply sticking with passing an argument?

Comment: if `.get_data('a')` becomes `.get_a()`, and you say "_can be any string_" the what would `.get_data('bla_bla')` become, specially if there is a `.get_data('bla bla')` as well ? which are two diffenent stings.

Comment: The reason of this question: I am re-implementing a DataReader class which has lots of methods like get_blabla, but the codes are similar. So I want to just define few get_data methods and remove the get_blabla methods to make the class clear and smaller. But for point of calling, there are already lots of outer codes call get_blabla, and I cannot change that codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach of passing the name to `get_data` seems pretty reasonable to me. But if you insist on using the attribute based lookups, you can override `__getattr__` and use `get_data` to in there for lookups e.g.:

```
class DataReader:
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        parts = attr.partition('_')
        if parts[0] == 'get' and parts[-1] != 'data':
            return self.get_data(parts[-1])
        return super().__getattr__(attr)

    def get_data(self, name):
        return name
```

Now you can use `Foo().get_a` to get `Foo().get_data('a')`.

If you want get the value from a callable like `Foo().get_a()` instead of `Foo().get_a`, you can use tuck in a `lambda`:

```
class DataReader:
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        parts = attr.partition('_')
        if parts[0] == 'get' and parts[-1] != 'data':
            return lambda: self.get_data(parts[-1])
        return super().__getattr__(attr)

    def get_data(self, name):
        return name
```

Now you can do `Foo().get_a()`.

Answer (score 2):

One method is having the `DataReader` to define `__getattr__` special method (that method is invoked when attribute is not found inside the object):

```
class DataReader:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.items = data.copy()

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if attr.startswith('get_'):
            return lambda: self.items[attr.split('get_')[-1]]
        raise AttributeError('Attribute "{}" not found.'.format(attr))

d = DataReader({'a':1, 'b':2})
print(d.get_a())
print(d.get_b())
```

Prints:

```
1
2
```